# Special plural forms without -s

Tags: grammar, defective-nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Irregular plurality situations in English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/irregular-plurality-situations-in-english)

**'sheep, deer, fish**' are some of a row of animals where singular and plural have the same form, i.e. the plural (normally) has no -s. But of course there are cases when the normal plural with -s can be used.

Is there any information why there is such a peculiarity?